# Textbooks on the Riemannian geometry of homogenous manifolds

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, quotient-spaces

I'm curious to learn more about homogenous manifolds, particularly the Riemannian geometry. As you know, homogenous manifolds are quotient manifolds of Lie groups. As a result, I'm curious what properties a metric on the parent Lie group induces on the quotient metric on the homogenous manifold. What can a geodesic on the parent Lie group say on the homogeneous manifold, and vice versa? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You might find [these survey notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03227.pdf) helpful.